# Why scrollbar is behind sticky elements in iOS Safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, css-position, sticky

When using `position: sticky;` in a container with `overflow-y: auto;`, the container's scrollbar is rendered behind the sticky elements. 
 In the following screenshot, the vertical scrollbar is behind elements 1, 2, 3, and 4.

[image]

But it works well when I remove the `height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto;` from the container and scroll inside the body element.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 100vh; 
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .stickyHeader {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #eee;
            height: 40px;
        }
        .item {
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='stickyHeader'>1</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>2</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>3</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>4</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>5</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question/problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` solves the issue.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 100vh; 
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: lightblue;

            /* fix */
            -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        }
        .stickyHeader {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #eee;
            height: 40px;
        }
        .item {
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class='stickyHeader'>1</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>2</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>3</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>4</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class='stickyHeader'>5</div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Downside is that it creates a new stacking context. Doesn't work for me. iOS is really behind...